# array.index dont print number

Tags: python, arrays, indexing

I have a problem with return even index in array.

```
def checkio(array):
if len(array):
    return ([i for i in array if array.index(i) % 2 == 0])
else:
    return 0

print (checkio([-37,-36,-19,-99,29,20,3,-7,-64,84,36,62,26,-76,55,-24,84,49,-65,41]))
```

and this code return

```
[-37, -19, 29, 3, -64, 36, 26, 55, -65]
```

but if i change '84' in my array for example for '74' its return

```
[-37, -19, 29, 3, -64, 36, 26, 55, 74, -65]
```

What the problem is it?

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that `84` appears twice:

```
print (checkio([-37,-36,-19,-99,29,20,3,-7,-64,84,36,62,26,-76,55,-24,84,49,-65,41]))
                                               ^^                     ^^
```

However, `array.index()` returns the index of the *first* occurrence. This happens to be at an odd index so all occurrences of `84` get suppressed.

If you just want to take every other element, simply write `array[::2]`. This will take elements at indices 0, 2, 4, etc. No need to do any lookups.